# Execute dynamic function with param in javascript

Tags: javascript

If the following possible? 
I wish to move the alert(result) into a function and to dynamically call it.

**Current**

```
$.ajax(this.href, {
    success: function (result)
    {
        alert(result);

        AjaxComplete();
    }
});
```

**My Attempt - not working**

```
$.ajax(this.href, {
    success: function (result)
    {
        window["MyAlert(result)"]();

        AjaxComplete();
    }
});

function MyAlert(result)
{
    alert(result);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you just do this?

```
MyAlert(result);
```

If `MyAlert` is a part of the `window` object, it's already a global.

Unless you want to call an arbitrary function by name (which isn't really good practice, IMO), which you can do like this:

```
window[function_name_string](argument);
```

Comment: because I want to store the function in an attribute. data-ajax-onsuccess-withparam

Answer (score 1):

```
window["MyAlert(result)");
```

is invalid syntax (missmatching `[` and `)`, wrong function name, and not calling it at all, just getting it..). Should be

```
window["MyAlert"](result);
```

if you want to call it like that, but I see no reason why you couldn't just call it normally, as Blender mentioned.

Comment: ahh yes, the ]) thing was a typo from typing the question. Thanks